# Finding undirected cycles in linear time (triangulating graphs while minimizing degree)

Tags: algorithms, graphs

In the article ["Triangulating Planar Graphs While Minimizing the Maximum Degree"] by Kant and Bodlaender [1], Section 4 briefly mentions the extraction of elementary cycles (no repeating edges) from what I assume is an undirected graph $H$. It has the following to say:

> $H$ is planar and bipartite.
>
> ...using a simple modification of Euler's technique to find an Eulerian cycle in a graph, we can extract the elementary cycles $C_\mathrm{elem}$ from $H$.
>
> Thus $H - C_\mathrm{elem}$ consists of paths $P$ with disjoint begin- and endpoints.

In the proof section it mentions that extracting elementary cycles and disjoint paths can be executed in linear time, allowing the triangulation algorithm as a whole to do the same.

From what I understand, there are no algorithms that compute the simple cycles of an undirected graph in linear time, raising the following questions:

- Which algorithm does "Euler's technique to find an Eulerian cycle" refer to? There seem to be several algorithms with varying performance.
- What is the "simple modification" in question? The paper doesn't say, and I haven't been able to find anything on the net.

---

[1] G. Kant and H. Bodlaender, "Triangulating Planar Graphs While Minimizing the Maximum Degree". *Information and Computation*, 135:1(1–14), 1997. ([Science Direct](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540197926353))

Comment: The paper mentioned in the post has various editions. However, not all of them contain the "extracting elementary cycles" part in Section 4. So I have added a link to an edition which does contain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Which algorithm does "Eulers technique to find an Eulerian cycle" refer to?

It probably refers to the [Hierholzer algorithm (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path#Hierholzer.27s_algorithm) which takes *linear time*.

The algorithm below is from the wiki article.

1. Choose any starting vertex $v$, and follow a trail of edges from that vertex until returning to $v$.
   It is not possible to get stuck at any vertex other than $v$, because the even degree of all vertices ensures that, when the trail enters another vertex $w$ there must be an unused edge leaving $w$.
   The tour formed in this way is a closed tour, but may not cover all the vertices and edges of the initial graph.
2. As long as there exists a vertex $u$ that belongs to the current tour but that has adjacent edges not part of the tour, start another trail from $u$, following unused edges until returning to $u$, and join the tour formed in this way to the previous tour.

> What is the "simple modification" in question?

Hierholzer algorithm aims to apply to Eulerian graphs which are (and should be) graphs with every vertex of even degree. In your problem, $H$ is not necessarily an Eulerian graph.

So it needs modifications: In step 1, the closed tour from $v$ to $v$ may not exist at all; and in step 2, you may not be able to start another trail from $u$, or you may not be able to return to $u$.

> Thus $H−C_{elem}$ consists of paths $P$ with disjoint begin- and endpoints.

This can be seen from Figure 7(b) in the paper.

Comment: Will accounting for those two cases produce the path-set P? Assume a graph with 3 black and 3 white vertices, having edges B1-W1, W1-B2, B2-W2, W2-B1 (cycle 1), W1-B3, B3-W2 (cycle 2 along with B1 or B2) and a dead end B3-W3. If cycle 1 is selected initially, no more tours will be joined to it. But $H$ - $C$ is a tree rather than a path.

Comment: @Aeris130 The tree can be decomposed into two paths, for example, $W_1 \to B_3 \to W_3$ and $W_2 \to B_3$ which have disjoint begin- and endpoints. Is this allowed for the following processing?

Comment: @Aeris130 Are there any other constraints on the graph $H$? In the same paragraph, I find that `Recall that H is bipartite, and all white vertices have degree 2 ` (however, Figure 7(a) does not agree with this).

Comment: The text mentions degree 2 for white vertices after discussing how to add edges from the cycle/paths to the final graph, so I assume it refers to the cycle and internal path vertices and not $H$ (since all three figures in the article contradicts this). As for decomposing trees into paths, nothing is said about it. Only that $H$ - $C$ = $P$.

Comment: @Aeris130 Also in the same paragraph: Call vertices $v''$ representing the 2-subgraphs $V''$ *black* and the other vertices of $H$ *white*. This may pose degree constraints on *black* vertices. For example (just a guess), all black vertices have even degrees. If this is true, your example graph is not a counterexample.